# Cancel AFNetworking 2.0 Success Blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I have a project where I need to cancel all of the current network requests using AFNetworking. I am using this to cancel them, but the success callbacks are still being called. Is there a way to ensure that the success blocks never get called after canceling the operations?

```
[[MYClientClass mysharedClient] operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];
```

Where, MyClientClass is a subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post code how you start a single operation?

Answer (score -1):

Calling cancelAllOperations on an NSOperationQueue should cancel all operations on it, and consequently prevent any of those operations from calling any their success/failure blocks.

If you're seeing the success/failure blocks of requests being fired, it's likely you either forgot to add them to an operation queue, and started the operation directly without a queue, or you added them to different operation queue that you forgot to cancel all operations on.

If possible, could post some of your code showing how you've created on of these requests operations that encounters this issue? It would help to diagnose your issue more specifically.

Comment: when you cancel operation you receive
Failed to load: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x10b444cb0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxxxxxx.com}